# Issue opening multiple tabs with javascript

Tags: javascript

Having issues with opening several tabs at once with javascript, my attempt is below:

```
<a id="download" href="#">Download All</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
var link = document.getElementById("download");

link.onclick = function() {
    window.open('logs/orders/26438/C%20S20%202131410.docx','_blank');
    window.open('logs/orders/26438/L%20S20%202131410.docx','_blank');
    window.open('logs/orders/26438/B%20S20%202131410.docx','_blank');
    window.open('logs/orders/26438/C%20S60%207141202.docx','_blank');
};
</script>
```

Comment: can explain what problem you are facing?

Comment: it is not opening all the links, only the first :(!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/10b9k7rp/

Comment: Fiddle works for me, Firefox 34, Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Yeah, chrome's popup blocker is suppressing the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clear up for anyone confused by this issue, Lee Kowalkowski figured out it was Chrome's popup blocker that caused the issue! The code was correct.

Answer (score -1):

try changing the target from _blank to _parent and still if you got problem then remove href tag from attribute a. also refer http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp for further details. Also some browser blocks pop ups, this will sometime causes issue.

Comment: Adding "Also some browser blocks pop ups, this will sometime causes issue." when the question has already been answered, odd...